# Defining http/https conditions in Django local_settings.py

Tags: python, django, https, request, django-settings

I serve my assets from S3 and in my local_settings.py template in Puppet I have:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://<%= s3_bucket_name %>/'

STATIC_URL = 'http://<%= s3_bucket_name %>/static/'
```

Is there a way to add a condition based on incoming request to change the 2 variables above to switch between http and https? I mean if the request is http, I want to serve my assets over http, and if the request is https then I want to serve my assets with over https.

Please also advise if there is a better way of doing this. The goal is to be able to serve both http and https depending on request when assets are hosted in S3.

Your help is much appreciated.